# Calculating RMSE for Prophet Model in Python

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, facebook-prophet, forecast

I'm new to learning python, and I'm creating a time series model which predicts total sales each month using the Prophet model. I am needing help getting the RMSE of my model! Thanks!

```
from fbprophet import Prophet
#Creating Dataframe#
proph = train.groupby(['date_block_num'])[ 'item_cnt_day'].sum()
proph.index=pd.date_range(start='2013-01-01', end='2015-10-01', freq='MS')
proph = proph.to_frame().reset_index()
proph.columns = ['ds', 'y']
proph.head()
#Modelling#
model=Prophet(yearly_seasonality=True)
model.fit(proph)
model.head()
#Making future predictions
future_data = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=1, freq='MS')
forecast = model.predict(future_data)
forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail()
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if its still relevant. You will need to prepare a DataFrame that holds the actual values, lets call it `df_actual`. Then the following will calculate RMSE for you:

```
se = np.square(forecast.loc[:, 'yhat'] - df_actual)
mse = np.mean(se)
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cross_validation and performance metrics from prophet to get these error metrics. You can follow the link https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/diagnostics.html to get how to calculate the RMSE and other metrics using cross_validation in prophet.

Comment: Detailed explanations are always welcome, no need to wait for permission. See [answer] and then do [edit] your answer to include the details. An answer needs to stand on its own, because users in five years shouldn't have to contact you for the details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).