# how to apply the MSE and RMSE frequency indicators in the EMD method with Python

Tags: python

Hi help me with the code below I am working on a project but I am stuck: I am using the `EMD` method to decompose signals in `imfs` but the problem is I don't know how to apply the MSE and RMSE frequency indicators in these IMFs.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
from PyEMD import EMD, Visualisation

x = data[:, 0]  # Sélection du canal 1
# Création de instants d'échantillons
t = np.linspace(0, data.shape[0]/rate, data.shape[0])

emd = EMD()
emd.emd(x)
imfs, res = emd.get_imfs_and_residue()

# Tracage des IMFs
vis = Visualisation()
vis.plot_imfs(imfs=imfs, residue=res, t=t, include_residue=True)
```

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52149785/10452700)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's easy to do like this:

```
#IMF1
plt.plot(imfs[0])
```

Comment: Welcome to SoF, better to delete this as an *answer* and include your point as *Edit1* if you modify/edit your question.

Comment: @Mario: This appears to have been intended as an answer. If so, it should _not_ be edited into the original question. I've rolled back your edit to the question, and am marking this answer as "Looks OK". If I'm misunderstanding something, please explain why you believe this is a clarification and not an answer.